# Curvature of connection in tautological line bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, curvature, projective-space

I'm trying to find the mistake in the following computation: let $V$ be a (complex) vector space equipped with a hermitian inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, ${\rm P}V$ be the projective space of $V$ and $\mathcal{L} \to {\rm P}V$ be the tautological line bundle. As $\mathcal{L}$ is a subbundle of ${\rm P}V \times V$, it inherits a fiber metric via $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and so we may project the standard flat connection ${\rm D}$ on the trivial bundle to a connection $\nabla$ on $\mathcal{L}$. Now, sections of $\mathcal{L}$ correspond to homogeneous functions $\mu\colon V\setminus \{0\} \to \Bbb C$ of degree $-1$ via passing $x \mapsto \mu(x)x$ to the quotient. If $X \in \mathfrak{X}({\rm P}V)$, then the derivative of this map is $$({\rm D}_X\mu)_x = {\rm d}\mu_x(Xx)x+\mu(x)Xx,$$so since $Xx \in (\Bbb Cx)^\perp$ (since $T_{{\Bbb C}x}({\rm P}V) \cong {\rm Hom}(\Bbb C x, (\Bbb C x)^\perp)$), we obtain $(\nabla_X\mu)_x = {\rm d}\mu_x(Xx)$. And $x\mapsto {\rm d}\mu_x(Xx)$ is also homogeneous of degree $-1$.

The connection $\nabla$ is not flat, because it does not admit any local parallel sections ($\nabla \mu = 0$ implies ${\rm d}\mu_x|_{(\Bbb C x)^\perp} = 0$ for all $x$, which contradicts non-integrability of the horizontal distribution of the submersion $\Bbb S^{\dim V-1}\to {\rm P}V$).

But let's try to compute $R(X,Y)\mu$. First it seems we have $$\nabla_X\nabla_Y\mu = {\rm d}^2\mu(X,Y) + {\rm d}\mu({\rm d}Y(X)),$$where ${\rm d}^2\mu$ is ${\rm d}({\rm d}\mu)\colon V\setminus \{0\} \to {\rm Hom}(V,V^*)$ regarded as a (symmetric) bilinear form. This would imply that $$R(X,Y)\mu = {\rm d}\mu({\rm d}Y(X) - {\rm d}X(Y) - [X,Y]).$$I want to say this is zero because ${\rm D}$ is torsion-free.

> 1. What's precisely the screw-up here?
> 2. How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course, this is not the way I would calculate this. But I totally don't follow. Aren't $X$ and $Y$ vector fields on $PV$?

Comment: Hi @Ted, yes, vector fields on $PV$ regarded as maps $X:V\to V$ such that $\langle Xx,x\rangle = 0$ for all $x \in V$ (not necessarily linear, though). My advisor suggested a way to do it using coordinates (which is nice), but still doesn't explains the problem here (I need to understand why the obvious thing doesn't work so I can appreciate the "correct" way better).

Comment: How does that necessarily descend to a well-defined vector field? Boy, I sure live my adapted unitary frames. :)

Comment: I'm thinking that since $T_L({\rm P}V) = {\rm Hom}(L,L^\perp)$ for all $L \in {\rm P}V$, a vector field is a collection of linear maps $L \to L^\perp$, which I'm just collecting together in a single map $V \to V$. The fact that the values are taken in orthogonal complements translates into $\langle Xx,x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$, and each $X$ is homogeneous of degree 1 (although not linear)

Comment: (I'm always a bit wary of using frames; I like things to be intrinsic, and while computing it using frames is easier, most of the time I don't know how to express the end result without the frame itself, which sort of defeats the point for me...)

Comment: We'll agree to disagree on frames. This computation gives the negative of the Kähler form in minutes. So why does your expression have the right homogeneity to be an eligible answer (i.e., well-defined)? I don't in my head see your first formula, either.

Comment: Following what my advisor suggested, I do recognize the expression he got as the negative of the Kähler form, but you mean why is $x \mapsto {\rm d}\mu_x(Xx)$ homogeneous of degree $-1$? Since $\mu(\lambda x) = \lambda^{-1}\mu(x)$, differentiate both sides at $x$ and evaluate at $Xx$ to get ${\rm d}\mu_{\lambda x}(X(\lambda x)) = \lambda^{-1}{\rm d}\mu_x(Xx)$. The fact that $X$ is homogeneous of degree $1$ does kick in here.

Comment: No, I meant the later formulas.

Comment: Right. We might be close to figure out the screw-up then. What I had in mind was that $\nabla_X\nabla_Y\mu$ at the point $x$ is the derivative of $x\mapsto {\rm d}\mu_x(Yx)$ at $x$ evaluated at $Xx$. We have two occurrences of $x$ here, so a chain rule is in order. The first occurrence should give ${\rm d}^2\mu_x(X_x,Y_x)$ while the second should give ${\rm d}\mu_x({\rm d}Y_x(X_x))$.